# Xcode 4 SFML opengl

Tags: xcode, opengl, sfml

I'm using SFML in Xcode but i can't use any of the opengl functions for some reason, i've got calls to glVertex3f, gluPerspective etc but for some reason the code won't compile, i might have to link in the opengl libraries i'm not sure, does someone know what i need to do?

Comment: What compile errors do you get?

Comment: @rjs: Seeing your other answers, did you solved this one?

Comment: What version of OpenGL are you targeting? How did you set up the context.

Answer (score 0):

What you have to do is:

- Click on the project at the top of your hierarchy "MyProject"
- Then to the left of the tab that shows up, click on your target
- Click on "Build Phases"
- Expand "Link Binary With Libraries" and click on the plus (+)
- Search for "OpenGL.framwork" and add it

Then just build it and everything should work just fine.
Hope this helps someone, I had the same problem.